# Why sites show me always the message "captcha not correct"?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, noscript, captcha

I enabled option allow scripts globally but when I try to log in on some sites although I write correct captcha, they show me that it isn't correct.
I disabled addon noscript and haven't any issue. Shouldn't allow scripts globally have the same effect as disabling the AddOn, though without changing the base fingerprint?